# QML fails to load

Tags: qt, qml

I am a beginner to QML, just wanted to test the Hello WOrld program with it. It fails:

```
/home/saman# /home/saman/QtSDK/Simulator/Qt/gcc/bin/qmlviewer
Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!
Cannot find any Simulator supporting Qt version 4.7.4.0.
Aborted
```

I need to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not installed the Qt-SDK properly. Try to follow the installation instructions that came with the SDK or install it through your distributions package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing SDK (Qtcreator & Qt Kit) from **https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.0/5.0.0/** (*download required version depending on the platform you are working*). This would inturn contain samples & demos which will work flawlessly.

All the best!